# Where can I find an ISO of 12.04 for ARM?

Tags: release-management, arm

All I've found is PXE boot files, but no actual ISO image for the whole distribution.  I need an ISO image because I can't get through the firewall to let the machine pull packages directly from the source.  So, is there a 12.04 ARM image available somewhere?  How do I get it, please?

Comment: What machine do you have? It seems to be available in `.img.gz` files

Comment: ARM systems are not PCs; they can't just boot from a cd.  You have to burn a custom built image into their flash rom.

Answer (score 1):

There is none for non-OMAP chip. According to [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/) you will need to start with netinstall or bootimages depending the case:

- **OMAP** images can be found in the [release page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/) ([12.04.3](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/)): http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-13.04-server-armhf+omap.img
- **TEGRA** based devices [requires](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100#Installing_Ubuntu_12.04_or_Lubuntu_12.10_on_the_AC100):

  - Mini-usb cable
  - Host computer with linux (virtual or physical)
  - Usb-stick or sd-card (min. 1GB)
  - About 1-2h of your life (depending on the download-time)

  Also download:

  - There are two AC100 related files in the 12.04 [release directory](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/):
  - [Bootimage](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+ac100.bootimg)
  - [Presinstalled rootfs](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+ac100.tar.gz)
  - [nvflash](http://ac100.grandou.net/nvflash#debian_ubuntu_package): which is used to flash via a mini-USB cable the bootimage

  More detailed instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100#Installation).
- **IMX53**: is only available up Oneiric 11.10 http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/release/ubuntu-11.10-preinstalled-desktop-armel+mx5.img.gz
- There is other guide for **[Marvell Armada XP](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Server)** but those aren't commercially available according to the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

The entire ARM Architecture is extremely fragmented, essentially only the the processor architecture is consistent.  The platform differs between boards, so the concept of a generically bootable ISO is unrealistic.  Beyond the OS level difficulties, such as almost universally closed drivers, the boot mechanisms aren't standardized.

I would think of just getting something installed as embedded development, and work is required for each new device. Some devices have small communities, and if you're lucky images and install instructions can be located.

Ubuntu officially supports a VERY small list of development boards, apparently they also drop-off sometimes... :(  It's not really their fault, since the fragmentation puts an unrealistic load on distributions and developers. It still is unfortunate, especially when considering just how much potential exists with ARM.

I may be able to help, but you must add which device/board you have available.  I also want to mention these problems would disappear if/when a standardized platform/boot environment is specified and followed, such as UEFI/ACPI.

Comment: do you know any UEFI/ACPI ARM platforms available today?