# Allwinner A10 crane board (mk802+) to run Ubuntu Server

Tags: arm

I have an **MK802+ Android Mini PC** that I want to run Ubuntu Server on, and use it as a **media client with XBMC**. The MK802+ runs on a Cortex A8 (Allwinner A10 chipset).

I downloaded a **Linaro Saucy** snapshot rootfs for armhf, and replaced the kernel modules with linux-sunxi sun4i, created boot uImage and uboot and boot.scr.
It works, but is **highly unstable**.  The device freezes up for no apparent reason, which leads me to believe the Linaro release may not have been the best route.

**Is there an Ubuntu 12 or 13 rootfs for armhf (cross-compiled)** that I can do the same with?

The real question is: is there a **downloadable rootfs for omap3** that I can simply download and replace the kernel modules as I did with the Linaro rootfs?

Comment: I reverted from the latest Linaro saucy server to a more stable developer release, it seems to be a bit more reliable.

Comment: I think this answers most of your questions. http://askubuntu.com/a/352038/169736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention that the MK802+ has an A10S, not an A10 like MK802. Although rootfs is very similar, kernel is NOT. I'm running linux-sunxi sun5i (not sun4i like you mentioned) for about a month without any problems.

Comment: I just checked the Wikipedia link @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Mini_PC_MK802#History_and_models  And it seems to confirm what you said.  Can't believe I missed it before.  I don't think it makes a difference though, I am using the Sun4i kernel, as per the website http://linux-sunxi.org/Linux_Kernel#Compilation A10 and A10s runs the same kernel config.  Rootfs compiled for armhf should work on armhf CPUs.  I think there might be another issue causing the instability (like maybe the poor choice of memory card I made...)

Comment: Hi Bruno.  I haven't looked at this in a while, finally found a link that outright states the A10s is sun5i.  Could have saved myself a lot of trouble if I just listened to you in the first place :-| It is not in my nature to take information on face value without proof.  And here it is: http://linux-sunxi.org/Mali400

And all this time I have been experiencing GPU driver issues as well, which prompted me to read up on the Mali400.  Anyway, thanks.